# What is the equivalent of Linux's && for windows

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, script

What is the equivalent of Linux's && for windows

For example

```
cd\
cd rcA
powershell "ls | where {$_.Length -lt 100gb} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse"
```

What to add to make the script stop if `cd rcA` can't be executed. For Linux it would be  `cd rcA &&`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd

Answer (score 2):

#### What to add to make the script stop if `cd rcA` can't be executed?

You use `&&` in `cmd` as well:

```
cd rcA && powershell "ls | where {$_.Length -lt 100gb} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Conditional Execution AND OR IF - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)